# Change or redirect Wordpress URL code for default WPML language

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wpml

I have a Wordpress site with WPML and for SEO reasons I need to stick to a fixed URL pattern for all the languages (including the default language):

https://my-site.com/de-de

Unluckily the WPML default pattern is like this:

https://my-site.com/de

... and the language code cannot be changed in the admin once the language is active (+ I have to set the primary language at WPML setup).

I tried to hack the language code in the icl_languages SQL table but there are too many dependencies. The WPML Support told be that I can create a custom language e.g. 'German (Germany)', then I can assign the URL code de-de to it. Then I should bulk duplicate all content (250 pages) and finally change the default language to the custom language but it is experimental and not recommended to use a custom language as default language.

Is there an easy and elegant way to hack the language URL or redirect seamlessly via .htaccess?

Thanks for reading and any ideas are welcome!

Comment: The most "elegant" way I know is to do what the support told you. :) You can also fiddle with redirect rules in .htaccess but that's usually more brittle.